# Trigger an event by shake in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I am trying to detect shake event with react native expo-cli but I am getting an error. I have properly installed react-native-shake from npm.

Take a look at my code and error screenshot.

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import RNShake from "react-native-shake";

export class Shaker extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    RNShake.addEventListener("ShakeEvent", () => {
      console.log("Shaked");
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    RNShake.removeEventListener("ShakeEvent");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Shake your Phone</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Shaker;
```

[image: error-image]

Comment: Which version of react-native-shake you are using

Comment: react-native-shake version "react-native-shake": "^4.0.2"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shake, check the demo, for above 4 version it is different

Comment: I have tried it but getting same error